# Change HTML background image on click

Tags: html, css, image, background

How to change background image on click i have this code

```
html { 
  background: url(img01.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

i have 5 div's with . 4of them are hidden . When i click on button it show's me next div and hide previous . When it show me the next div i want also to show new background image under div. How to do that :(

```
<div id='2' style="display: none;">
    <input type='button' div_funkcija(2);" value="Sehr-Gut">
    <input type='button' div_funkcija(2);" value="Gut">     
    <input type='button' div_funkcija(2);" value="Befriedigend">
    <input type='button' div_funkcija(2);" value="Ausreichend">
    <input type='button' div_funkcija(2);" value="Mangelhaft">
</div>
```

And the script is

```
function div_funkcija($div) {
    document.getElementById($div).style.display='none';
    document.getElementById($div+1).style.display='block';
}
```

Now when it open's the new div how to show on body or html background the new image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code which helped

```
<input type='button' Onclick="document.body.style.cssText+=';background-image: url(Cistoca.jpg);background-repeat: no-repeat; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover;  background-size: cover;'" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function div_funkcija($div)
        {
            document.getElementById($div).style.display='none';
            document.getElementById($div+1).style.display='block';
            document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.backgroundImage='url(newImage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed';
        }
```

Or you can give the html tag an ID and use document.getElementById.  Just an additoinal suggestion, I don't usually style the html tag, usually I reference the body.

Comment: I'm not so good with this . What if i have like 10 same div's and i need to change background image under each. All backgrounds are different. Where i will put the images :( :(

Comment: You could store the image url in a data attribute like:

    <input type='button' div_funkcija(2);" data-bgimg="imageURL" value="Befriedigend" />

Then access that value with something like:

    document.getElementById(inputID).getAttribute('data-bgimg')